# What's rust's idiomatic way of writing vector into a file (or as a string) with tabs between elements and newline at the end?

Tags: rust, iterator

I encounter this problem fairly often. Every time I write a vector into a file or turn it into a string I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing this.
My (fairly ugly) code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    let as_string = vec
        .iter()
        .take(vec.len() - 1)
        .fold("".to_string(), |acc, elem| {
            acc + &format!("{}\t", elem)
        })
        + &format!("{}\n", vec.last().unwrap());
    
    print!("{}", as_string);
}
```

As you can see, I would like to iterate over all except the last element and append a "\t" after each vector-element unless it's the last element. In this case I want to append a "\n" after the element.

I'm wondering if there's a simpler way of doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The approach you're taking as well as the other answer will result in an unnecessary heap allocation to hold the string before writing it out.  This is not only inefficient but may not even be feasible for large vectors.

Consider instead creating a wrapper that implements `Display`:

```
use std::fmt::Display;

struct DelimitedSequence<T, D>(pub T, pub D);

impl<T, I, D> Display for DelimitedSequence<T, D>
where
    T: IntoIterator<Item = I> + Clone,
    I: Display,
    D: Display,
{
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        let mut items = self.0.clone().into_iter();

        if let Some(item) = items.next() {
            write!(f, "{}", item)?;

            for item in items {
                write!(f, "{}{}", self.1, item)?;
            }
        }

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Now you can just do `println!("{}", DelimitedSequence(&some_vec, '\t'))`.  This also works with `writeln!` on I/O-capable values such as `File`.

Aside from not requiring an allocation, this approach is also generic over all of its input, allowing you to use any value that can be converted to an iterator of `Display`-able items, as well as any delimiter implementing `Display`.

(Be mindful that the value implementing `IntoIterator` is cloned, which is basically free for a reference to a vector, but is *not* free for a vector itself.)

Comment: Note for the OP in csae it's not obvious: `format!("{}", DelimitedSequence(&some_vec, '\t'))` yields a string.

Comment: Ok, that's cool. But one question: how is this more efficient when it's cloning the vector? Wouldn't that also allocate memory?

Comment: @exocortex If you pass in a _reference_ to the vector, as my example does, then it is only cloning the reference, which is just a bitwise copy (which will also likely be optimized away). `&Vec<T>` implements `IntoIterator<Item = &T>`.

Comment: If you don't want to roll your own [`itertools::Format`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.format) is essentialy this wrapper.

Comment: @cafce25 Nice. I see they took the approach of panicking on the second format instead of requiring the iterator be cloneable. Makes sense. I thought about doing something similar and storing `RefCell<Option<T>>` and `take`-ing it when formatting, but instead decided on the `Clone` bound.

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is to have simple and idiomatic code, I'd call `Vec::join()`, which takes care of special-casing the last element. The result has a similar number of lines, but is a bit easier to follow:

```
let as_string = vec
    .iter()
    .map(|n| n.to_string())
    .collect::<Vec<_>>()
    .join("\t")
    + "\n";
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=649516e35966db4a06557004bc50b341)

Do note that this performs allocations that could be avoided. In hot loops and other high-performance code you might want to replace it with an explicit `for` loop that uses `write!(output, "{n}\t")` directly (special-casing the last element, as your original code did), or use the technique from the other answer.