# How can I serialise multiple documents to the same file with `serde_yaml`?

Tags: rust, serialization, yaml, deserialization, serde

I've got a `Vec<Foo>` and I want to serialise it to a single YAML file containing multiple YAML documents, separated by `---`, like so:

```yaml
foo_key: foo_value
other_key: 123
other_other_key: []
---
foo_key: bar_value
other_key: 312
other_other_key: [other_item]
---
foo_key: baz_value
other_key: 123321
other_other_key: [item]
```

Is this possible? I know that I can deserialise the above file into a `Vec<Foo>`, using the following snippet:

```rs
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Foo {
    foo_key: String,
    other_key: String,
    other_other_key: Vec<String>,
}
let foos: Vec<Foo> = serde_yaml::Deserializer::from_str(&yaml_file)
    .filter_map(|doc| Foo::deserialize(doc).ok())
    .collect();
```

But I can't figure out how to serialise the `Vec<Foo>`.

---

edit: I'd rather not resort to joining each YAML doc with `---`, that seems to go counter to using a library for serialising YAML:

```rust
let serialised_foo_documents = foos
    .into_iter()
    .filter_map(|foo| serde_yaml::to_string(&foo).ok())
    .reduce(|acc, e| acc + "---\n" + &e)
    .unwrap_or_default();
```

Comment: You can just map `serde_jaml::to_string` over the vector and [join them with `"\n---\n"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77769803/442760)

Comment: Okay, I was hoping `serde_yaml` had an encapsulated way of doing this

Answer (score 3):

This can be done very similarly to deserialization:

```rust
let mut serializer = serde_yaml::Serializer::new(Vec::new());
for foo in &foos {
    foo.serialize(&mut serializer).unwrap();
}
let s = String::from_utf8(serializer.into_inner()).unwrap();
println!("{s}");
```

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly straight forward just reuse the same `serde_yaml::Serializer` like the [docs show you](https://docs.rs/serde_yaml/latest/serde_yaml/struct.Serializer.html):

> ```rust
> use anyhow::Result;
> use serde::Serialize;
> use std::collections::BTreeMap;
>
> fn main() -> Result<()> {
>     let mut buffer = Vec::new();
>     let mut ser = serde_yaml::Serializer::new(&mut buffer);
>
>     let mut object = BTreeMap::new();
>     object.insert("k", 107);
>     object.serialize(&mut ser)?;
>
>     object.insert("J", 74);
>     object.serialize(&mut ser)?;
>
>     assert_eq!(buffer, b"k: 107\n---\nJ: 74\nk: 107\n");
>     Ok(())
> }
> ```

so for your `Vec<Foo>` that would be:

```rust
for foo in &foos {
    foo.serialize(&mut ser)?;
}
```